# angularjs ui updated slow in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the demo http://jsbin.com/ogiyej/9/edit

When I choose the first option to 'a',

then choose the second option to 'a1'

the third option will be changed into several options like "a11 a12 a13" etc.

But when I change the first option to 'b'

then choose the second option to 'b1'

in **firefox** the third option changed to the 'b1''s district very ***slowly***;

**chrome** work well.

Both browsers were updated to the latest version.

(In firefox if I click the second option several times,ui will be updated soon)

Comment: create fiddle in English, then people will be able help you.

Comment: Sorry I have changed the demo into English,but in jsfiddle it doesn't work well,so I use jsbin